# Updated valgrind suppression file for GTK

Tags: c, gtk, valgrind, gtk3

I am currently working with a GTK application written in C and trying to find memory leaks with valgrind, but it is very hard to find my own memory leaks among the thousands of leaks generated by GTK.

Therefore I am looking for an up to date suppression file for GTK3, but no matter how much I search I only seem to find dead links and very old suppression files that do not actually suppress the errors.

Some links that I've found that are either too old or dead:

- https://wiki.gnome.org/Valgrind / [https://people.gnome.org/~johan/gtk.suppression](https://people.gnome.org/%7Ejohan/gtk.suppression) / https://github.com/dtrebbien/GNOME.supp
- https://gist.github.com/bert/758760
- https://github.com/pwithnall/walbottle/blob/master/libwalbottle/tests/walbottle.supp
- http://lug.rose-hulman.edu/code/projects/grits/repository/revisions/master/raw/src/gtk.suppression
- http://paste.org/47748

Comment: Whats wrong with "/usr/share/glib-2.0/valgrind/glib.supp"?